# Как увеличить размер логического тома root - / если к нему ещё и привязан снимок (snapshot)?

Tags: lvm

Это в lvm - когда я захожу с live cd пишет деактивируйте root раздел, после деактивации пишет для изменения размера раздел должен быть активирован. Я деактивировал снимок на нём. Единственно не пробовал дополнительно деактивировать и том root но вроде он автоматически деактивируется при деактивации snapshot

Comment: Решено удалением snapshot.